# Find all tables which are not used in a given period in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

Trying to find a SQL query which can list all the tables which are not used in a given period of time in oracle.

Below query returns all the tables for the owner:

```
select tablespace_name, table_name
from ALL_TABLES
where owner ='HP';
```

I execute the below query to get some statistics on table read and write, unfortunately it returns error table not found:

```
SELECT *
FROM v$segment_statistics
WHERE owner = 'HP';
```

Is there any way I could include a date factor filter the table depending on a range?

Comment: you need a select permission on that view, or 'select any dictionary' grant for this

Comment: If you have the Diagnostic and Tuning license, you can get the information from `DBA_HIST_SEG_STAT` view.

Comment: @access_granted now permission is given, but that table does not have any date related information

Answer (score 1):

By "all the tables which are not used in a given period of time" you mean any usage? Remember, there's direct usage: SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE. There's also indirect usage, such as enforcement of foreign keys. The indirect usage will be hard. Also bear in mind that some objects might only be used seasonally (for instance, if your application has business cycles such as quarterly or year-end reporting).

So this is an Auditing problem. You could find this information using Oracle's standard AUDIT capability. It is not switched on by default because there is an overhead to recording DML activity. The overhead of logging each time a SELECT is issued against a table could be noticeable if you enable it for all tables. So use it with care.

```
AUDIT SELECT TABLE, UPDATE TABLE, INSERT TABLE, DELETE TABLE;
```

[Find out more](https://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/db112/SQLRF/statements_4007.htm#SQLRF01107).

Auditing will give a record of every time a DML action happens on a table. This is obviously more information than you need. But that's what there is.

You mention the possibility of using `v$segment_statistics`. This is one the dynamic performance views, which are not granted to regular users by default but ask your DBA. As you have noted it is just a running count of statistics, with no date or timestamp column. If your organisation licenses the [Diagnostic pack](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/license.112/e47877/options.htm#DBLIC165) you will find a historical record of these stats in the AWR view [DBA_HIST_SEG_STATS](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/server.112/e17110/statviews_4031.htm).

If you have AWR working anyway it is a simple matter to leverage this data to track which tables are being used. But if you don't have the necessary license you will have to maintain your own history of `v$segment_statistics` and check for deltas yourself. This only needs to be a daily task run from a background job.

---

This all seems pretty complicated for what on the face of it ought to be a simple task. Oracle seems to think that we should have a good understanding of all the tables in our schema. But alas in my experience developers are more willing to create tables then they are to drop them. Consequently    there are legacy systems out there with wildly overgrown schemas and no simple way to do impact analysis, because too much SQL is embedded in external DAO contrivances.

Answer (score 0):

This problem generally requires some snapshotting of the information in v$segment_statistics, unless widespread auditing is practical, which is usually not the case for a busy database.  Particularly, check for changes in the 'logical reads' and 'db block changes' statistics to see evidence of reads and/or writes to the table.  However, statistics gathering could throw this approach off for ruling out application reads, unless dbms_stats is used with OPTIONS of 'GATHER AUTO' or 'GATHER STALE' (because stats collection will generate logical reads.)  Those options only collect statistics on those tables with a significant number of changes since the previous stats collection, so tables not getting inserts, updates, or deletes would never have stats collected.  (This assumes the statistics_level parameter is set to at least 'typical', which is the default.)

The default stats collection job in Oracle 11g does use 'GATHER AUTO', as documented [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E25054_01/server.1111/e16638/stats.htm#i41282).  You can confirm if that is being used with the following query:

```
SQL> select client_name, status from dba_autotask_client;

CLIENT_NAME                          STATUS
------------------------------------ --------
auto optimizer stats collection      ENABLED
auto space advisor                   ENABLED
sql tuning advisor                   ENABLED
```

If the default stats collection is happening and manual stats collection on all tables is not happening, you might start by checking the last_analyze time:

```
select table_name, last_analyzed from all_tables
where owner = 'HR' order by last_analyzed;
```

Suspect unused tables might be those with older values for last_analyzed.  If only writes are a concern, one could check the all_tab_modifications:

```
select table_name, inserts+updates+deletes as change_count, timestamp
from all_tab_modifications where table_owner = 'HR';
```

If it is required to check for reads, then AWR (requires Diagnostic Pack license) has snapshots of the segment information in the dba_hist_seg_stat view.  Without Diagnostic Pack, Statspack can populate segment information into stats$seg_stat at statistics level 7 or above.  ([More on Statspack levels](https://jonathanlewis.wordpress.com/2007/01/14/statspack-levels/).)  However, both of these can prove a table *is* being used but not that a table is unused.  The reason is that both tools select only a limited number of "top" segments.

To get a definitive answer, you probably need to make your own snapshots of the information.  A very simple approach can start by creating a table like this:

```
create table my_segstat as select sysdate as snap_date,
  object_name, object_type, statistic_name, value
from v$segment_statistics
where owner = 'HR' 
  and statistic_name in ('logical reads', 'db block changes') ;
```

Then set up a job to periodically add snapshots of the information with a query like this:

```
insert into my_segstat as select sysdate as snap_date,
  object_name, object_type, statistic_name, value
from v$segment_statistics
where owner = 'HR' 
  and statistic_name in ('logical reads', 'db block changes') ;
```

Later, the data can be analyzed building upon a query like this one:

```
select snap_date, object_name, statistic_name,
  value - lag(value) over (partition by object_name, statistic_name
                           order by snap_date) as delta
from my_segstat;
```

Of course, there could be other things reading or writing should-be "unused" tables that might throw off this approach to analysis as well.